# Thumbnailator Image Rotation messes the image

Tags: image, rotation, javax.imageio

I am trying to rotate images using Thumbnailator library. The code that I use is as shown below. It rotates the image or flips the image successfully but the color quality completely spoils. The input and output images are also shown.

```
package com.abk;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.ImageReader;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream;

import net.coobird.thumbnailator.Thumbnails;
import net.coobird.thumbnailator.filters.Flip;
import net.coobird.thumbnailator.filters.Rotation;
import net.coobird.thumbnailator.util.exif.ExifUtils;
import net.coobird.thumbnailator.util.exif.Orientation;

public class ImageAutoRotate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("314.jpg"));
            BufferedImage newImg = Rotation.RIGHT_90_DEGREES.apply(img);
            BufferedImage flipImg = Flip.HORIZONTAL.apply(img);

            File outputfile = new File("314_2.jpg");
            ImageIO.write(newImg, "jpg", outputfile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Input Image
[image]
Output Image
[image: Output Image]

Comment: The result looks like YCbCr incorrectly interpreted as RGB.

Comment: The image is RGB itself... Is there a way to force it to interpret the image as RGB

Comment: The original is stored as YCbCr (most JPEGs are), but decoders convert this to RGB. The output is probably RGBA (4 channels) before you write it, but as the JPEG contains an Adobe marker with "unknown" transform, the image is interpreted as CMYK (!)... Quickfix: Use PNG for output OR change the image to `TYPE_3BYTE_BGR` or `TYPE_INT_RGB`.

Comment: Checked - the original is RGB. And the output comes as CMYK for some reason. So I need to understand how to get the output as RGB

Comment: Not really. The *decoded* original is RGB, yes. But the *file* contains YCbCr (you can see this by inspecting the image metadata if you like). The result before encoding is RGBA, and this is encoded as YCbCrA. However, the output is *interpreted* as CMYK for the reason described above. Convert the image `TYPE_3BYTE_BGR` before writing, and you'll be good. I promise. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved the issue by saving the image as a PNG image. The issue was actually caused because the image profile was being treated as CMYK while saving

The final code to resolve this issue is shown at this [link](http://abhishekkothari.in/web-development/handling-exif-data-html-webpages/)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue it is due to the `ImageIO.write` class. Following is the approach I used.

```
//Here imagebuffer is an array of bytes you can convert it from bufferedimage

InputStream fiStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBuffer);

//Creating a file using byte array

FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File(path + "/webapps/northstar- 
primefaces-portlet/images/member/" + event.getFile().getFileName()), imageBuffer);

//Creating an output stream using the created file

OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(path + "/webapps/northstar-primefaces-portlet/images/member/"  + event.getFile().getFileName());
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Thumbnails.of(fiStream).scale(1).toOutputStream(outputStream);

//Now the outstream has the rotated image with the correct colours
```

Let me know if this helps.

Reference:
https://github.com/coobird/thumbnailator/issues/23